# Can't make cross-domain requests without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a web project where using jQuery (or other libraries/dependencies) is not an option, so I'm trying to replicate the code jQuery uses to make AJAX requests. The project previously used jQuery, so I've structured my replacement to the $.ajax() method to have the same behavior, however I cannot get mine to make cross-domain requests. When trying to load in scripts for example, I get this error in the console.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load <URL>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin <URL> is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm familiar with CORS and the whole cross-origin-security policy and what that entails, but what I'm confused about is how jQuery can seem to circumvent that, while my code cannot. I'm thinking there must be something special jQuery is doing?

This is how my $.ajax() replacement function is currently scripted.

```
function ajax (options) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in request)
        request.withCredentials = false;
    else if (typeof XDomainRequest !== "undefined")
        var request = new XDomainRequest();

    options.type = options.type || options.method || "GET";
    request.open(options.type.toUpperCase(), options.url, true);

    for (var i in options.headers) {
        request.setRequestHeader(i, options.headers[i]);
    }

    if (typeof options.beforeSend == "function")
        var go = options.beforeSend(request, options);

    if (go == false)
        return false;

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var resp = this.responseText;
            try {
                var body = JSON.parse(resp);
                this.responseJSON = body;
            }
            catch (err) {
                var body = resp;
            }

            if (this.status < 300 && typeof options.success == "function")
                options.success(body, this.status, this);
            else if (typeof options.error == "function")
                options.error(this, this.status, body);

            if (typeof options.complete == "function")
                options.complete(this, this.status);
        }
    };

    if (typeof options.data == "object" && options.data !== null)
        options.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);

    if (options.type.toUpperCase() != "GET")
        request.send(typeof options.data !== "undefined" ? options.data : null);
    else
        request.send();

    return request;
}
```

Can someone point out if I'm missing something obvious? Do I need to manually also do the OPTIONS pre-flight or something?

Comment: Since someone might mention this, I should point out that I do not have control over the server I'm making cross-domain requests to in this case. I'm trying to load cross-domain scripts, so doing something like settings "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to "*" on the server wouldn't be an option.

Comment: Was the previous code using JSONP, where the url to a resource is loaded via a script tag? Check the old code to see if it uses `dataType:'jsonp'` in the `$.ajax()` options, if so you will have to change your code around to handle that type of request

Comment: Or use a proxy either on your server or third party service

Comment: *"When trying to load in scripts for example, I get this error in the console"* don't load scripts in with xhr...

Answer (score 0):

I've found a fix for this. The issue seemed to stem from trying to load in cross-domain scripts specifically. jQuery uses $.getScript() to do that, which actually just adds a script to the page instead of making a cross-domain HTTP request.

I used this code as a replacement for that function.

```
function getScript (url, callback) {
    var loadScript = function (url, callback) {
        var scrpt = document.createElement("script");
        scrpt.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        scrpt.src = url;
        scrpt.onload = function () {
            scrpt.parentNode.removeChild(scrpt);
            console.log("Script is ready, firing callback!");
            if (callback)
                callback();
        };

        document.body.appendChild(scrpt);
    }

    var isReady = setInterval(function () {
        console.log(document.body);
        if (document.body) {
            clearInterval(isReady);
            loadScript(url, callback);
        }
    }, 25);
}
```